# get elements from nested array not existing in another nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Please, help!
I need to get list of elements in nested array that do not exist in another nested array,
example document:

```
{
"_id": 123,
_a: [
  {
    aid: 10,
    _p: [
      {
        pid: 1,
        x: "C"
      },
      {
        pid: 2,
        x: "B"
      },
      {
        pid: 4,
        x: "A"
      }
    ],
    _d: [
      {
        pid: 2,
        x: "M"
      },
      {
        pid: 5,
        x: "M"
      },
      {
        pid: 7,
        x: "M"
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
   { aid:10 , pid:5}
   { aid:10 , pid:7}
```

Task1:  I need to find all the _a[]._d[].pid that do not exist in _a[]._p[]

Task2:  I need to remove all objects from _a[]._d[] with pid that do not exist in _a[]._p[]

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sl7s3okBn2e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$setDifference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$_a"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      aid: "$_a.aid",
      pid: {
        $setDifference: [
          "$_a._d",
          "$_a._p"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$pid"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      aid: 1,
      pid: "$pid.pid"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tbNrS_rmEls)

Comment: updated the example document with closer structure but still reduced ( there is <20 fields in the sub-object inside the nested array ...  ( it is not only pid field inside the nested object )

Comment: $setDifference is working for array of values only or array of objects with single key;value  ... :(

Comment: aaah wait , it is working as follow : https://mongoplayground.net/p/kGRsBR7VqkP   , thanks alot!